# C-Programming: Received data is written to a pointer

Tags: c, memory-management, heap-corruption

so I have the following enum method in c:

```
enum enum_type GetInfo (int socket, unsigned char *data)
{
}
```

and at the api I can find this:

Received data is written to pointer *data....

So if I'm doing something like this:

```
unsigned char *data;
enum_type enum1;

enum1 = GetInfo (int socket, data);
```

I got an segmentation fault.

What's my problem?

Thanks,
Simon

Comment: The problem is that data is **not** "written to a pointer". It's written to an object pointed to by the pointer, but your pointer does not point to anything.

Comment: @Roman: he should fix the compilation errors too.

Comment: @JeremyP That's left as an exercise :)

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you haven't allocated space for `data` but try to write to it. Do

```
unsigned char *data = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * MYBUFLENGTH);
```

and then pass data to GetInfo. At the end do not forget to

```
free(data);
```

Alternatively you could allocate space on stack (available in C99, some compilers support it as extension even with earlier versions of the C Standard)

```
unsigned char data[MYBUFLENGTH];
```

In this case you should not worry about memory management.

Answer (score 2):

you need to allocate memory to store the data in.
for instance:

```
unsigned char data[10000]; /* allocate 10000 bytes */

enum_type enum1;
enum1 = GetInfo(socket, data);
```

If you don't understand what's going on, I recommend spending time to read up on [pointers](http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/pointers.htm).

Answer (score 1):

not sure how big the info is, but try the following

```
unsigned char data[512] = {0};
enum_type enum1;

enum1 = GetInfo (socket, data);
```

this makes sure, that data points to a valid memory address on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

It's maybe because `GetInfo` wants to write to a buffer pointed by `data`, and you just pass the pointer without allocating any memory space. Allocate memory and point it to `data` like this:

```
// I assume you need 1000 bytes
data = (unsigned char*)malloc(1000*sizeof(unsigned char));
```

Comment: Haven't you seen C tag? new comes from C++.